# Using crawlera proxy in VBA

Tags: excel, curl, proxy, web-scraping, vba

I am trying to scrape indeed.com and have bought crawlera service for dynamic IP as indeed blocks frequently.

Here is an example of how to use Crawlera with the curl command line tool:

```
curl -U key: -x proxy.crawlera.com:8010 http://httpbin.org/ip
```

For downloading HTTPS pages, I have to use certificate file. I am a beginner in VBA and I do not know how to use the proxy. I want to make use of this proxy to make requests in VBA, for fetching information.

```
 Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument
Dim SearchForm As HTMLFormElement
Dim WhatInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim WhereInputBox As HTMLInputElement
Dim SubmitButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim HTMLelement As IHTMLElement
Dim oInputs As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Listings As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, lngRetVal As Long
Dim TotalResumes As Long, ResumesPerPage As Long, TotalPages As Long, PageNo As Long
Dim firstURL As String, nextURL As String
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
Set myIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
myIE.Visible = False
Dim StringFound As Boolean
StringFound = False
If Len(Trim(Range("D1").Text)) > 0 Then
    StringFound = True
End If
If Len(Trim(Range("F1").Text)) > 0 Then
    StringFound = True


If StringFound = True Then
    Const cURL = "http://www.indeed.com/resumes?co="
End If

ie.Navigate cURL & Mid(ActiveSheet.Shapes("Country").ControlFormat.List(Range("J1").Value), InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Shapes("Country").ControlFormat.List(Range("J1").Value), "(", vbTextCompare) + 1, 2)

Application.StatusBar = "Going to the Website........."

If Right(Range("H1").Value, 1) = "\" Then
    myFolderPath = Range("H1").Value
Else
    myFolderPath = Range("H1").Value & "\"
End If
Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Application.StatusBar = "Going to the Website........."

Do
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE '= 4
Sleep 5000
Dim ieElement As Object
Dim ieElement2 As Object
Set ieElement = ie.Document.getElementById("query")
ieElement.Value = Range("D1")
Set ieElement2 = ie.Document.getElementById("location")
ieElement2.Value = Range("F1")
ieElement.Document.getElementById("submit").Click
Do While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.StatusBar = "Searching for Resumes........."

Do
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE '= 4

Sleep 5000

Range("A3:K1048576").ClearContents
Set doc = ie.Document
firstURL = doc.Url
If Len(doc.getElementById("result_count").innerHTML) = 0 Then
    MsgBox " No results found " & vbCrLf & "Pls check the website", vbCritical
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    myIE.Quit
    Set myIE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
```

How can I use crawlera proxy to make requests? I tried searching how to make this request but couldn't find one that could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Function GetResult(url As String) As String
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, ret As String
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setProxy 2, "proxy.crawlera.com:8010"
    XMLHTTP.setProxyCredentials "APIKEY", ""
    XMLHTTP.send
    ret = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
    GetResult = ret
End Function

Sub TestCrawleraVBA()
    Debug.Print GetResult("http://httpbin.org/ip")
End Sub
```

Don't forget to replace **APIKEY** with yours.

Comment: Yes, this works but if you see my code I am using internet explorer. I will have to configure internet explorer to use proxy settings and check the proxy provided by crawlera is working.